# Get Column Header of file as rows in TALEND

Tags: talend

Trying to get all column name from a file into distinct rows.

Using tfileinputdelimited and limit is set to 1 to only pick Header Row.
Header row will be like COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4

Need to capture each in a distinct row and assign a sequence value.

Output:
COL1,1
COL2,2
COL3,3
COL4,4

Note: Need to perform this for multiple files which might have different number of columns in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to retrieve the header row as a single string, with a tFileInputDelimited using one column only in the schema and a delimiter different than the actual delimiter in the file, like a "@".
Once you have the header row, you can pass it to tNormalize to convert the comma separated list to rows.
The output from tNormalize can then go through a tMap in order to add a sequence number:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to get the Columns are Rows. The tmap could output as rows like `COL1 1 \n COL2 2 \n COL3 3`

Comment: I don't understand. The tMap is already outputting each column name in its own row along with the sequence, notice how there's one incoming row, but 4 outgoing rows from tNormalize and tMap. I'm just logging the data with tLogRow but you could write it to file.

Comment: Does tNormalize not work with caret symbol ^. I tried with "," then its working but not with "^"

Comment: The separator field in tNormalize can take a regular expression, that's why the caret doesn't work as it's a special character in regex. You need to escape it by adding double backslash: \\^

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks